# Installing geth errors

Tags: geth

I'm working on a web3 project and need to access the web3.geth.txpool functions. For that, I used an infura node but it seems it does not work. I did a little bit of research, and came to the conclusion that I need a geth node. As there are no free online options out there, I tried to run a node myself: I run the exe from the go ethereum website. After I run the exe, I run the command "geth" in cmd, but it says the command does not exist. Anyone got any idea?

My pc runs on windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

G'day mate, GETH is not that simple to install or run. If you've installed from a pre-built exe package you will still need to run the geth commands at command line.
Not an expert, have had to rebuild my system a few times and just reinstalled GETH again for the 3rd time but on a Linux OpenSUSE machine.

Here is links to GETH commands, I think you will need to type something along the lines of

$ geth --syncmode "full"

or

$ geth --syncmode "fast"

or

$ geth --syncmode "light"

depending on what node you need to run.

https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/run-light-node-geth/

Also this should help if you already didn't find it;

https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options

Comment: And after the cmd is running, how do I connect to it using python web3?

Comment: Yo my bad, I didn't see this notification, have you got this sorted yet?
If not go here. https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.geth.html